# Fluent Mappings: mapping collection error

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have 2 collection mappings, one is working and the other is not. I cannot figure out why.

```
public class ProjectMappings : ClassMap<Project>
{
    public ProjectMappings()
    {

      HasMany(x => x.Commits).Table("tCommits").Cascade.All().KeyColumn("fRC_Commit_ID").ForeignKeyConstraintName("fRC_Project_ID");

        HasMany(x => x.Competencies).Table("tCompetencies").Cascade.All().KeyColumn("fIC_ID").ForeignKeyConstraintName("fIC_Project_ID");
    }
 }

public class CommitsMappings : ClassMap<Commit>
{
    public CommitsMappings()
    {
        Table("tCommits");
        Id(x => x.Id, "fRC_Commit_ID");

        Map(x => x.ProjectID, "fRC_Project_ID").Not.Nullable();
    }
}

public class CompsMappings : ClassMap<Competency>
{
    public CompsMappings()
    {
        Table("tCompetencies");
        Id(x => x.ProjectCompetencyID, "fIC_ID");
        Map(x => ProjectID", fIC_Project_ID").Not.Nullable();
    }
}
```

If I run the code:
Project.Competencies.Clear();  - all competencies are cleared from a project
If I add a new comp to a project I can simple add by: Project.Competencies.Add(item);

However my mappings for Commits seems to throw for some reason,

**Message :Cannot update identity column 'fRC_Commit_ID'.**

What does this mean? Why does this happen?

I am trying to delete some competencies, add some new ones, and create a new commit to show what has changed on the project. On Transaction.Commit() I get the error above.

#### Question: What is the correct way to map these 2 collections to a Project?

Answer (score 1):

- the keycolumn on points to the iod instead of the foreignkey column
- the table can be ommited because Commit is its own entity with its own table
- since you have a backreference to project you can let the backreference maintain the foreign_key. set inverse on the Collection to mark that

Code

```
HasMany(x => x.Commits)
    .Cascade.All()
    .KeyColumn("fRC_Project_ID")
    .Inverse();

// change Map(x => x.ProjectID, "fRC_Project_ID").Not.Nullable(); to
References(x => x.Project, "fRC_Project_ID").Not.Nullable(); // where Project property is of type Project
```